# Hide a window in cocoa from awakeFromNib

Tags: cocoa

I have a NIB with two NSWindow objects.  The controller class has two IBOutlets, one for each NSWindow (windowLogin and windowMain).

I only want one of the windows visible on launch.  Insdide awakeFromNib I am using:

```
[windowMain orderOut:self];
```

which is having no effect.  However, if I try:

```
[windowMain setTitle:@"Renamed Title"];
```

It works as expected.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look for the "Visible At Launch" property in the attributes inspector for the window in Interface Builder.

Comment: I have then used [windowMain makeKeyAndOrderFront:self] as required.

Comment: However this a sure sign of a weak design. You will generally find in the long run that having one window per nib is a better idea. Create dedicated NSWindowController subclasses for each window/nib and have them load as needed.

Comment: @MikeAbdullah Although generally true, your advice far from a "sure" sign. :-) For all we know, the OP's app is a very small, simple app with only two windows. In that specific case, the usual benefits of using separate nibs (performance and maintainability) are actually negatively impacted, especially if the secondary window is likely to be used in a session. Even if the secondary window is rarely loaded, is saving the user one millisecond at launch time worth making your app more complicated to maintain?

Comment: (ran out of room) Good performance should be a primary goal, yes, but that one millisecond isn't cumulative. It's a one-off savings. But now your very simple app project has more files to navigate and maintain. If you know it's always going to be small and have the same basic UI, separating nibs in the name of "future proofing" is premature optimization of both your app's performance and your project's organization. Just some food for thought. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, in ApplicationDidFinishLoading, you can call [window setIsVisible:NO]